# JTRevealSidebar initialized from tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I would like to implement the JTRevealSidebar project (a sidebar feature very similar to the sidebar in the facebook app) into my project. My only problem is that my main view from where i want to initialize the sidebar is a UITableView, and not a UIView, which the JTRevealSidebar is setup for. Has anybody tried setting this up before with a tableview or know if it's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return any subclass of UIViews in your sidebarDelegate callback

```
- (UIView *)viewForLeftSidebar {
    // Use applicationViewFrame to get the correctly calculated view's frame
    // for use as a reference to our sidebar's view 
    CGRect viewFrame = self.navigationController.applicationViewFrame;
    UIView *anyView = self.leftView;
    if ( ! anyView) {
       anyView = [[AnySubclassOfUIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
       [self.view addSubview:anyView];
    }

    return anyView;
}
```